# My web page is not running my JavaScript validation code

Tags: php, javascript, html

Okay, so I have the form set to my PHP page.  I also have the submit button `onsubmit` set to my validation javascript.  What happens is that it goes directly to my php page and does not validate the input?  What am I missing?  Do I have this set up right? If I remove the php file from the form the javascript validate works fine.  It is trying to use the php and javascript together that drives me insane.

```
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
      <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles_Final.css"/> 
      <title>contact.html</title>   
         <script type= "text/javascript" src = "scripts/validator.js"></script> 

      </head> 

      <div id="right-cont">

        <form name = "contact_Us" action="http://nova.umuc.edu/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/ct386a28/eContact.php" method = "post"> 

            <div id="style2">
                <p>Please enter contact information below:</p>                                 
            </div>

            <div class="style7">
                <label>First Name: </label>
                &nbsp;<br /><input type="text" name = "firstName" id="firstName" tabindex="1" 
                    style="width: 176px" />
            </div>  

            <div class="style7">
                <label>Middle Name: </label>
                &nbsp;<br /><input type="text" name = "middleName" id ="middleName" tabindex="2" 
                    style="width: 176px" />
            </div>

            <div class="style7">
                <label>Last Name: </label>
                &nbsp;<br /><input type="text" name = "lastName" id ="lastName" tabindex="3" 
                    style="width: 176px" />
            </div>         

              <div class="style8">
                <label>Questions and/or comments: </label>
                &nbsp;<br /> <textarea name = "comment" id = "comment" rows = "10" cols = "60"></textarea>
              </div>             

          <div class =" buttons">
            <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick = "return validate()"/><input type="reset" value="CLEAR"/> <br />                
          </div> 
          </div>              
       </form>
   </div>
```

***********************JAVASCRIPT*************************************************

```
   function validate() {
   //create references
   var fName;
   var mName;
   var lName;
   var email;
   var phone;

   fName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;  
       mName = document.getElementById('middleName').value;  
       lName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;  
       email = document.getElementById('email').value;  

       //validate the phone number     
       phone = document.getElementById('phone').value; 
       var boolean = isPhoneNumber(phone);

       if (!boolean)
       {
           alert("Please enter valid phone number format: ddd-ddd-dddd.");
           return false;
       }  

       //validate the email address
       email_Val()

       //validate the first name
       var fN=document.forms["contact_Us"]["firstName"].value
       if (fN==null || fN=="")
       {
          alert("Please fill in first name.");
          return false;
       }

       //validate the last name
       var lN=document.forms["contact_Us"]["lastName"].value
       if (lN==null || lN=="")
       {
       alert("Please fill in last name.");
       return false;
       }


   }

   function isPhoneNumber(phone)
   {
       var str = /^\(?[2-9]\d{2}[\)\.-]?\s?\d{3}[\s\.-]?\d{4}$/
       return str.test(phone);
   }

   function email_Val()
   {
       var eM=document.forms["contact_Us"]["email"].value
       var x=eM.indexOf("@");
       var y=eM.lastIndexOf(".");
       if (x<1 || y<x+2 || y+2>=eM.length)
       {
          alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address");
          return false;
       }
   }
```

Comment: Without seeing the `validate` function, it'd be hard to answer.

Comment: Is `validate()` defined?  Is an error being thrown?  Where is it defined?  Does it return false if validation fails?

Comment: Is the Javascript on the page correct, you have an `onclick` on the `<submit>` button, but otherwise nothing can be seen.

Comment: The setup looks right, but there's probably something going on with the `validate()` function.  If there is a JavaScript error, the JavaScript code will bomb out and let the form be submitted.

Comment: I have added the javascript file above.  In the heading section I have made a link to the seperate javascript file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a link to a working version of your code: [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/826Wr/12/)

The easiest way to correct it is just to make sure you included the javascript in the `head` of your document, whether it's a link to an external file (preferably) or just inside the HTML. Then, check for syntax errors in your javascript, this might sometimes cause the code not to execute properly (or at all).

In your case, you did also try to access fields that did not exist in the code, which caused an error, and when an error is thrown the browser stops validation and just submits the form.

Here's the working version of your code:

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
      <head>

      <title>contact.html</title>   

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function runValidate() 
 {

   //create references
   var fName;
   var mName;
   var lName;
   var email;
   var phone;
   
   fName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;  
       mName = document.getElementById('middleName').value;  
       lName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;  

       //validate the first name
       var fN=document.forms["contact_Us"]["firstName"].value;

       if (fN==null || fN=="")
       {
          alert("Please fill in first name.");
          return false;
       }

       //validate the last name
       var lN=document.forms["contact_Us"]["lastName"].value;
       if (lN==null || lN=="")
       {
       alert("Please fill in last name.");
       return false;
       }


 }

function isPhoneNumber(phone)
{
   var str = /^\(?[2-9]\d{2}[\)\.-]?\s?\d{3}[\s\.-]?\d{4}$/
   return str.test(phone);
}

function email_Val()
{
   var eM=document.forms["contact_Us"]["email"].value
   var x=eM.indexOf("@");
   var y=eM.lastIndexOf(".");
   if (x<1 || y<x+2 || y+2>=eM.length)
   {
      alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address");
      return false;
   }
}
          </script>
      </head> 
<body>
      <div id="right-cont">

        <form name = "contact_Us" action="http://nova.umuc.edu/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/ct386a28/eContact.php" method = "post"> 

            <div id="style2">
                <p>Please enter contact information below:</p>                                 
            </div>

            <div class="style7">
                <label>First Name: </label>
                &nbsp;<br /><input type="text" name = "firstName" id="firstName" tabindex="1" 
                    style="width: 176px" />
            </div>  

            <div class="style7">
                <label>Middle Name: </label>
                &nbsp;<br /><input type="text" name = "middleName" id ="middleName" tabindex="2" 
                    style="width: 176px" />
            </div>

            <div class="style7">
                <label>Last Name: </label>
                &nbsp;<br /><input type="text" name = "lastName" id ="lastName" tabindex="3" 
                    style="width: 176px" />
            </div>         

              <div class="style8">
                <label>Questions and/or comments: </label>
                &nbsp;<br /> <textarea name = "comment" id = "comment" rows = "10" cols = "60"></textarea>
              </div>             

          <div class =" buttons">
            <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick="return runValidate();"/><input type="reset" value="CLEAR"/> <br />                
          </div> 
          </div>              
       </form>
   </div>
```

Comment: Actually putting javascript at the head of the document does not run as fast as putting it at the end since it is a blocking load.  This will only matter on very complex websites, but is still worth pointing out.  Just because Dreamweaver did it that way does not mean it was the best way to go.  http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Comment: True, but that's why I said the `easiest` way - at least it ensures it works, even if the page hasn't fully loaded yet when the user clicks the button. If you need your website to load as fast as possible, put it right before the closing `</body>` tag, and load the script on document ready. I thought about saying this in my answer, but decided not to complicate things.

Comment: @Herman - ok semantics -- I read the "make sure you included the javascript in the head of your document" as an absolute statement. Cheers.

Comment: @Hogan - Also, did Dreamweaver do that? Haha, the good old days.

Comment: @Herman - Yes, I believe that is where the practice gained widespread use.  (Might have been a compatibility issue too with browsers that would try and parse it as html).

Comment: @Hogan - The convention of putting `<script>` in head may also come from the [HTML 3.2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#script) where, although a close inspection of the DTD shows that it is allowed in both head and body, the prose so strongly implies that `<script>` is an child of head that I suspect that it must have been quite a late change to allow it in body as well. This probably influenced the writers of both Dreamweaver and the HTML tutorials of the time.

Comment: @Alochci - that makes a lot of sense.  Have to wait for `computerhistory.stackoverflow.com` before we can ask the question :D

Answer (score 1):

Are you positive the javascript which contains the validate() function is included in your php?  Do a view source on the page and double check.

Comment: Whoa! Okay . . . you mean that I am supposed to include the Javascript in the actual .php file itself?  The way I have it set up right now is that the validate is actually in a .js file called validator.  It is set up in the header. . . Let me try it . . .

Comment: Okay it doesnt seem to matter where the javascript page is, it still doesnt validate it.  I will put the javascript validation file in the text area above.

Comment: Can you use Tools->Error Console in Firefox to see perhaps if there's a syntax error in your JS?  This would also make it appear as though it's not running.

Answer (score 1):

Try folowing code for the submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick = "validate()"/><input type="reset" value="CLEAR"/> <br />
```

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that you have some syntax errors in your Javascript code, but also you are trying to access fields that are not declared in the HTML (such as phone and email).  I've modified your Javascript, and it does what I think you expect that it should be doing:

```
 function validate() 
 {

   //create references
   var fName;
   var mName;
   var lName;
   var email;
   var phone;

   fName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;  
       mName = document.getElementById('middleName').value;  
       lName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;  

       //validate the first name
       var fN=document.forms["contact_Us"]["firstName"].value;

       if (fN==null || fN=="")
       {
          alert("Please fill in first name.");
          return false;
       }

       //validate the last name
       var lN=document.forms["contact_Us"]["lastName"].value;
       if (lN==null || lN=="")
       {
       alert("Please fill in last name.");
       return false;
       }


 }
```